# Excel VBA - If Else still performing Else

Tags: vba, for-loop, if-statement

My code is fairly simple but a bit puzzling. I might be committing a minor error - pardon my newbie-ness. The Sheets.Add.Name line still gets executed despite having Boolean = True, thus a new worksheet is created with the Sheet# naming convention.

Sharing my code:

```
Private Sub create_analyst_btn_Click()

Dim strUser As String
Dim DateToday As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim boolFound As Boolean

strUser = newanalyst_form.user_User.Value

For Each ws In Worksheets

    If ws.Name Like strUser Then boolFound = True: Exit For
    Next

    If boolFound = True Then
        MsgBox ("User already exists.")
    Else
        DateToday = Format(Date, "-yyyy-mm-dd")
        Sheets.Add.Name = strUser & DateToday
        Unload Me
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What does the debugger show you when you step through that code? I don't think you understand exactly what it's doing.

Comment: When do you ever reset `boolFound` for those subsequent iterations? It'll be true after the first one, and then true forever after.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I could use a new T-shirt. :-)

Comment: @Ken White 
"Run-time error '1004': That name is already taken. Try a different one.

I think the concatenation of the sheet name in the else statement is not properly recognized to be unique despite appending DateToday.

Comment: Try `ws.Name Like strUser&"*"` instead of `ws.Name Like strUser` in the **if** statement.

Comment: Um, no. That's not what debugging that code does.

Comment: @Marc -- on the contrary my boolFound seems to be set to false forever, after executing the code successfully in the first attempt.

Comment: Issue resolved.

bulbus' first suggestion worked, same with Tim Biegeleisen's. Appreciate the help guys.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the point of the first `If` statement and I would refactor your code to the following:

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "*" & strUser & "*" Then
        MsgBox ("User already exists.")
        Exit For
    Else
        DateToday = Format(Date, "-yyyy-mm-dd")
        Sheets.Add.Name = strUser & DateToday
        Unload Me
    End If
Next ws
```

The logic here is that if the name already exists before calling the subroutine, we would discover this while iterating, display a warning message in an alert box, and exit.  Otherwise, the name/date would be added to the sheet.

Comment: `For` without `Next`?

Comment: Actually, if the **first** worksheet in the workbook does **not** match the user name, that `If` statement will create a new sheet.  And then it will attempt to create a second new sheet if the **second** worksheet in the workbook doesn't match.  ( I won't say "etc", because it will crash trying to create the second copy with the same name as it created because of the first worksheet not matching.)